# Floating action button dissapears when scrolling

Tags: java, android

I have problem with dissapearing Floating action button. Inside viewpager I have fragment with recycler view and when I scroll button shown behind all layouts, and its not sticked to its anchor.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    ​
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

        android:id="@+id/materialup.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >
        ​
        <RelativeLayout
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/materialup.toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"

                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"

                />
            <LinearLayout
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
                android:id="@+id/materialup.title_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                >

                ​<monkeys.signme.utils.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/materialup.profile_image2"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:elevation="8dp"

                />
                ​
                ​
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>​

        <LinearLayout
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        </LinearLayout>


        ​
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            android:id="@+id/materialup.tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    ​

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/materialup.viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
    ​
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        app:backgroundTint="#fff"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:elevation="2dp"

        app:layout_anchor="@id/materialup.title_container"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"

        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"


        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />
    ​
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Please help.